# Does a triangle exist with its sides in the relation $x^n + y^n = z^n$ (where $z$ is the "greatest" side)?

Tags: geometry

My friend gave this to me at school, and I have been grilling at it for hours

[image]

My idea is to prove that $k>1$, so I can write $x>z-y$. I am also not too sure of this approach.

Edit: I am sorry to have left out the most important thing

x,y,z,n ∈ N and n>2

Comment: $z^n=x^n+y^n<(x+y)^n$ for $n>1$, so $z<x+y$

Comment: Of course a triangle exists with its sides in the relation $x^n + y^n = z^n$ where $z$ is the greatest side (no "scare quotes" required). The question is, does such a triangle still exist if it must also satisfy other constraints on $x,$ $y,$ $z,$ and $n$? What constraints did your friend have in mind?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does the case $n=2$ ring any bell?

Comment: For any triangle, each side must be less than the sum of other sides.

Comment: "I have been grilling at it for hours"  Top mathematicians of the world grilled at it for 350 years until Andrew Wiles provided a proof spanning 100+ pages, so don't be discouraged.

Comment: If it was just $x^n+y^n=z^n$ then yes I would agree that there is no simple way to tackle this problem however since this is a triangle we have $x^2+y^2-2xy\cos(\theta)=z^2$. Also $\cos(\theta)$ is rational because $x,y,z\in\Bbb{N}$ so all hope is not lost.